# How can SonarQube be used to view results for specific directories (packages) of a project?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I want to investigate how certain rules and issues have been violated in a certain package, however, from what I have seen in the Components-interface in SonarQube, it is only possible to view leaf node-directories and I am interested in viewing the entire folder, including sub-folders and files in that folder.

E.g.

```
Project 
   src
      package1
         subdirectoryone
            done
               code-a.java 
            dtwo 
               code-x.java 
            dthree
               code-i.java 
            code-1.java
            code-2.java
         subdirectorytwo
      package2
         subdirone
         subdirtwo
```

In this example I would like to investigate the issues and rule violations in `subdirectoryone` including the code files at all levels in the directory.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SonarQube 4.5 if you start from the dashboard and click the Issues link you will see all the issues for every module. In the left box below the lists of Severities and Rules is a list of all the modules and sub-modules in your project. If you select from that list it will narrow down the centre and right boxes to just the packages and files within that module. Unfortunately it doesn't filter the rules or severities in the top boxes.

In SonarQube 5.3 if you go to the issues tab you can select the module checkbox on the left side and select from your high runners. Near the top of the page is a hierarchy for the module you selected which you can click on to see the dashboard for that module or sub-module and then click issues for just that part. Then if you want a sub-module that isn't in high runners note that the URL is editable if you are careful and know your target hierarchy.

I haven't found a better way than that yet in 5.3, but after only a few days playing with a recent 5.3 upgrade I am generally liking the UI changes.

Comment: What do you mean by 
_[...] note that the URL is editable if you are careful and know your target hierarchy._

I edit the URL in what way? Could you please explain further?

Comment: After some further investigation I found out what you mean!

Comment: As I found it, this does not include the folders and files beneath this selected package, are you experiencing the same situation @Sinc?

Comment: As far as I know it will show you all the components of the package that have violations against them. I expect it to show everything within the package, including sub-directories.
With 5.3 you might get to see more files if you go in through the coverage tab, since I would expect that to show all files whether they have issues or not, since every file should have coverage (even if it's zero).

Comment: Not exactly what I need, but still helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I use something like this:

```xml
<sonar.projectName>Some project name (com/your-directory only)</sonar.projectName>
<sonar.exclusions>org/**/*, com/acme/**/*</sonar.exclusions>
<sonar.test.exclusions>org/**/*, com/acme/**/*</sonar.test.exclusions>
<sonar.sources>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/com/your-directory</sonar.sources>
```

This excludes everything but the code I want to be analyzed (exclusions properties) and define my source dir as `${project.build.sourceDirectory}/com/your-directory` (this is where the code I want to be analyzed is)

Then the analysis is run using maven:

```sh
mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent package -Dtest=com/your-directory/**/*Test.java
```

(note the `-Dtest=` restriction for the tests)

---

Some reading: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Narrowing+the+Focus

Comment: I see! What I was looking for was an approach to narrow the focus once I had analyzed the entire project, i.e. an approach to "set the scope" in the SonarQube interface. The closest feature which I have found which matches that is the **Code** tab (which is named Components in SQ5.3 and previous versions).