# How can I get to a directory/package view with SonarQube?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36083992/how-can-sonarqube-be-used-to-view-results-for-specific-directories-packages-of) existing question, but the answer suggests to use modules and submodules. But unfortunately our large project contains of exactly **one** module. Which has millions of lines of code, thousands of bugs and hundreds of thousands of code smells.

From my point of view, I am mainly interested to quickly get to certain directories within that huge thing to check the issues for the 50 directories or so that I am responsible for.

A coworker suggest to write a small script that turns a file system directory name into a URL that I could use on the sonarqube server, like turning

```
/a/b/c
```

into something like

```
https://..../code?id=ourModule&selected=zEndCon%a%b%c
```

That would probably work, but I find that really cumbersome. And of course: that allows me to switch between individual directories. But I am rather looking for some code of directory-based view where "subdirectories statistics" are accumulated.

SQ version is `Version 6.7 (build 33306)` - and given the comment by Julien: basically I do "not see" how the code tab helps me. The code tab tells shows me the first 100 of 3000+ directories. I don't see an easy way to get to a directory that would be like the 1247th directory in that list.

Comment: Which version of SonarQube are you using ? Starting latest LTS 6.7, using the code tab should work for you.

Comment: You can use the search box to search for directory you're interested to

Comment: @JulienL.-SonarSourceTeam I don't see how I could search for directories. The only thing that works is: searching for a class in one of the directories. When opening the file, I can then click on the corresponding directory. But then one is stuck again. Is there a way to like go up/down the directory structure from there?

Comment: It's not possible to navigate up/down in the directory structure, so I have no solution for you, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigating up/down in directories is not possible in SonarQube, and there's no plan for the moment to implement this.

Feel free to start a thread on the [Google mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube), explaining your use cases, as StackOverFlow isn't the place to start a discussion about a new feature.

Comment: I don't know... For me people will upvote if they feel the same need as you. If they don't, they won't upvote it !